# cannot reproject postgis in mapserver

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, mapserver

I am trying to set up a wms server using point data in a postgis (v 1.5.1, pgsql v 8.4)  database and mapserver (v 1.5.1) (I know these are not the most current versions of anything, but my server is running debian stable, if neccesary, I'll upgrade them).

The data is a global data set, so the points are stored in lat/lon as postgis geography data type. I manage to display the data (using either arcmap 10 or Qgis 1.8 or directly in a web server) in lat,lon, but I would like to be able to serve the data in other projections as well. I have tried to set up LAEA north pole (EPSG 3408) as well. In the GetCapabilities, I get a part like this:

```
<Layer>
    <Name>xxxx</Name> 
    <Title>yyyy</Title> 
    <Abstract>zzzz</Abstract> 
    <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS> 
    <CRS>EPSG:3408</CRS> 
    <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
       <westBoundLongitude>-50</westBoundLongitude> 
       <eastBoundLongitude>90</eastBoundLongitude> 
       <southBoundLatitude>-50</southBoundLatitude> 
       <northBoundLatitude>90</northBoundLatitude> 
    </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
    <BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-50" miny="-50" maxx="90" maxy="90" /> 
</Layer>
```

I.e my two projections are listed, but I only get the bounding box for the original projection. SHould I also get the other one?

As far as I can see from the instructions I can find, I just need to list the projections I want to use in wms_srs in the METADATA section - in the layer, in the MAP or both places (I've put it both places, but I've also tried it in just the layer or MAP, with the same result)

Comment: What specific mapserver product are you trying to configure?  This doesn't look like a mapfile from the OSGEO MapServer project.

Comment: What is shown is a part of what is returned from a  GetCapabilities query - not the mapfile...

Comment: It is still not clear to me what 'MapServer' product you are using.  I am assuming that you have a typo above and that you are running MapServer 6.x, not 1.5.1.  Correct?

Comment: I am using the OSgeo mapserver (http://mapserver.org) and, of cource the version number was a typo, sorry for that. I am using v 5.6.7

Comment: Not sure when it was introduced (it came out of INSPIRE requirements), but you can now get bounding boxes for all supported CRS by using `"WMS_BBOX_EXTENDED" "TRUE"` in the WEB > METADATA block

Answer (score 1):

According to the OGC WMS Spec, which I won't quote directly for fear of violating the license agreement...

In a WMS GetCapabilities:

- each  shall have at least one
- if a layer supports on-the-fly transformation to multiple CRS, the server implementation does not need to provide a  element for CRS beyond the CRS of the original.  I don't know if you can configure MapServer to explicitly advertise all potential .

[OGC WMS Spec](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=14416)

You state that you want to serve the data in multiple CRS, but you don't say if it works or not.  According to the WMS Spec, there is nothing wrong with your GetCapabilities.  Have you tried a GetMap request to see what the data looks like?  That would be the real test.